# Why notifications sound is controlled by media sound settings?

Tags: samsung, notifications, audio, android-10, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I have a Samsung Galaxy S9+ with Android 10 and I have the following problem - in the sound settings, I have media and ringtone set to halfway, but notification and system sound set to 0. But I can still hear notification sounds, and they are as loud as I set the media sounds settings. Why are notification sounds controlled by the "media" and not the "notification" setting? How can I fix this, to have silent notifications, but still hear music?

Comment: Are you talking about all notifications or notifications of a specific app? May be the app that plays the notification sounds just plays them using the regular media API and thus they are controlled by the media volume.

Comment: It happens to more than one app. I am sure that Messenger and Outlook have this issue, I don't remember if other apps do it as well.